# Need Help identifying LEGO castles

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

would anyone be able to assist with identifying the following 2 LEGO castles? We’ve tried looking on the catalogues so far but no luck. If anyone can assist, I’d appreciate it :) thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid these aren't pure LEGO sets. I can spot many non-LEGO elements and accessories, which explains why it is hard to find in LEGO catalogs.

Answer (score 2):

In your first photograph I spot what seems to be [Panel 1x4x5 Wall with Window in dark bluish gray](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60808#T=C&C=85):

[image: Panel 1x4x5 Wall with Window dark bley]

The [list of sets containing such a part in that colour](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60808&colorID=85&in=A) is very short, and none of the sets resemble the construction in your photograph.

The second photograph seems to feature the same part, but in light bluish grey instead. Again, the [list of sets with that part in that colour](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60808&colorID=86&in=A) yields no matches.

It's safe to say that you're not dealing with LEGO sets, but with clone brands instead.

Comment: Also, the brown head on a pike in the top left corner of the first photo doesn't seem like a Lego thing to me.

Comment: And the 1x3x2 half arches, and the white cups used as torch holders, and the black helmets, and the inverted 2x2 slopes with four indentations. It's hard to make an exhaustive list.

Comment: My recollection of castle stuff is rather dated, but to me it looks like some  genuine parts (or very near copies) and some parts from clone brands that don't have genuine equivalents